# Font-weight changes with CSS3 Transitions

Tags: css-transitions

I'm on [working this page](http://www.evenpanda.com/content.php?team) currently. The font-weights of the team members and their names are perfectly looking uniform, but as soon as I hover over the photos to invoke the CSS3 transition, the font-weight becomes lower.

I have tried giving the photos div more margin-right, but the font-weight is still changing.

I'm using the latest Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two mistakes that leap out at me:

1) You have two divs both with the ID of "team". That's pretty much guaranteed to confuse browsers.

2) The divs with IDS of "#about-pic" and "#about-team" have their "display" property misspelled as "dispplay" in your CSS. The value isn't being applied. Fix that typo and the type stabilizes on the hover event.

Comment: Thanks! I have amended the spelling error as well as making it into 4 separate IDs, but the issue remains.

Comment: Weird. Those changes in Chrome Dev Tools fixed the issue for me at least in Chrome. You've changed the page completely now though, so it's impossible to see. Please repost a working link if you still want help with this.